# html form input method get prevent name in url if value is not filled

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, form-helpers

Let's say this is my html in reactjs/jsx:

```
<form action="/search-list" method="GET">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and when i click on the `submit` buttoin without inputing anything, it make the url like this `fname=&lname=`

and when i fill anly `fname` and submit, the url become like this `fname=JhonDoe&lname=`

Notice here, i didn't fill the `lname`, yet the `lname` is here in url which i dont want.

I want, if a field has `value`, that field should be in `url` as query params, if not field, that field should not be in `url` query params.

is it possible to do? how can I do it? All the fields should be optional.

Comment: would be a jQuery solution helpful?

Comment: I am using reacjts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plain JavaScript to remove the empty inputs from submitting.

```
<form method="GET" id="myForm">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    Form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    Form.addEventListener('submit',()=>{
    if(Form.fname.value == ""){
    Form.fname.name ="";
    }

    if(Form.lname.value == ""){
    Form.lname.name ="";
    }


    Form.submit();
    });

</script>
```